# Possible to restore phone-only contacts from PC backup?

Tags: contacts, sync, data-recovery

I have a Samsung S4 which I did factory reset on, after backing up my data to my PC via USB.  I grabbed everything off the "phone" and "card" directories and backed up to an external drive on my PC.  I assumed that this would be enough to protect my data, but it looks like the phone-only contacts (not the ones synced with Google) are no longer available. (I didn't have Verizon backup assistant turned on lately enough to catch the contacts.) I've read that there should have been a db file in one of the directories, but I don't see anything like that in what I backed up.  Someone else wrote that I needed "root" to get to those files, but wouldn't those files have come through the USB backup?  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well its possible to restore any contact present on the Personal Computer provided your method of backup was done using a dedicated software like Samsung Kies.
For Samsung Kies follow the below Steps

1. In Samsung kies it provides two kinds of restore phone only restore
   or complete (SIM+ phone).At first after installation of Samsung
   kies3
2. Samsung  kies has currently two versions Samsung kies and Samsung kies 3.Samsung Kies is for basic mobiles as well as smart phones with Android version upto Android 4.1 As yours is Android 4.2 above device kies 3 is suitable for you.
3. After installation all your backup is to be taken and stored
4. So whenever you lose data or do a firmware upgrade you will have
   your data always with you safely